# Can't get boolean from other script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an UI button and when I press it, I want a particular object from the scene to be activated.

"spawn At" script is on the button and when i press it will use the "USE" method.
"turretOn = true;"

and on my other script I want to know when the Bool "turretOn = true;"
to Set.Active Obj from my scene
[ i tried to drag the object to the button UI " on Click" but i cant put it there]

[image: Script on UI Button]
[image: Script on "game manager type of object"]

Mine Debug.logs sends all the prints of the first script [" USE TRUE"\ "PArty"] but nothing from the other script

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `SpawnAT = GetComponent<SpawnAT>();` line from code because its already script object you don't need to get its component.
[image]

And make sure you set the button as in the image.

Comment: Ty, but do u know how can i fix the problem?

Comment: Just delete the 13th line from SpawnATactive.cs.

Comment: its still not working :( any more ideas?

Comment: Did you do the one in the picture?